# Error 503 first byte timeout, Angular SSR firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-universal

I have set up an Angular App to use SSR with firebase hosting using this [tutorial](https://codeible.com/view/videotutorial/XTwjaMmUAHuRPPCLUnbQ). Its been working well but every so often I will get a timeout error shown below. The functions in firebase show it just as a timeout. If I reload using the root of the project it works fine but I cant refresh on loaded routes. Its not consistent. I have tried to increate the ram to 4GB and set the timeout to 180s. When it works it loads in less than a second. Is there something I need to go with firebase or google hosting to fix this?

After further testing this issue only occurs on my default start route.

```
const mainjs = require(__dirname + "/server/main");
    exports.ngssr = functions.runWith({ memory: "4GB", timeoutSeconds: 120 }).https.onRequest(mainjs.app);
```

Below is the error

```
Error 503 first byte timeout
first byte timeout

Error 54113
Details: cache-cpt13828-CPT 1654107757 2005438016

Varnish cache server
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add brackerts like  mainjs.app -> mainjs.app()